# Yahoo news CSS, how to achieve behavior

Tags: css

how can I achieve this with CSS

[image]

by "this" I mean the white part which is inclined.

any suggestions ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you look at their source code to see what they use?

Comment: Why don't you use your dev tools and inspect the elements? You have all the code already inside your browser, just go find it.

Comment: I am using Ionic. Is there any special technic ? I am programmer, not a CSS guy. But you both are right, thanks.

Comment: Why are guys downvoting the question ? somebody gave an answer below. That's something I really hate from this place, if you don't get what I am asking, then just ignore the question, don't do that.

Comment: It's downvoted probably because you showed no effort what so ever.

Comment: I haven't start yet, I was asking for any special technic or any suggestions. COME ON! @putvande

Comment: This website is not about suggestions, it's about helping those who show a little effort in doing it. And you are also rude.

Comment: @machineaddict rude because I said that I am not a css guy ??? HAHAHAHAHA don't cry baby. Sorry, and thanks to the people who provided some answers :)

Comment: I was trying to be constructive, as you didn't show any sign of effort, but you continue to be rude. Learn how to be humble, rudeness will not get you far in life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need CSS clipping. The below CSS should give you the desired effect.

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 54%);
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 54%);
```

You can use this tool to work out exactly what effect you would like.
[CSS Clip-path Marker](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

**Usage**

```
div {
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    background: #1e90ff;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 54%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 54%);
     }
```

Comment: That's great bro, I am unable to see that in the css on the browser.

Comment: It's not supported by IE though.

Comment: I need it for a mobile app, so in this case it doesn't matter. GREAT :)

Comment: What do you mean you are unable to see that in the css in the browser?

Comment: I really hate those guys downvoting the question, I was just asking for any recommendation or something, Yisus

Comment: @DanCundy I will connect my phone to the MacBook, so I will check that css.

Comment: You need to add it to your CSS file for it to work. @NietzscheProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
transform:  rotate(X deg) scale(1) skew( X deg) translate(0px);
```

Maybe you'll need 3 diferent divs, one for the pic, one to rotate and another one to place the text (with differents z-indexes)